# Create new Dispatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app I need to create a new `Dispatcher` for a `Thread`. Usually, we can make it this way:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

ManualResetEvent dispatcherReadyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    dispatcherReadyEvent.Set();
    Dispatcher.Run();
})).Start();

dispatcherReadyEvent.WaitOne();

dispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

The problem is that using Windows Phone 8.1, I haven't access to the `Thread` class. I don't understand how I can create a Thread and extract a Dispatcher from it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is the same for all your App

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the dispatcher of the current thread (maybe the UI thread). I want to create another thread and use its dispatcher. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish? The `Dispatcher` should be used to gain access to the UI thread, of which there would typically be only one.

Comment: Imagine you have some threads. Each thread calls some functions in the whole system. At a certain point I wanna stop parallelism and I want to make the calls sequential  (following their order). I'd like to create a sort of channel. To do so I need a thread called, maybe, ChannelThread. If I had the dispatcher of that thread I can just call the functions on that dispatcher. So, I'll be sure the calls happen sequentially.

Comment: You can do this with events model in C#, why you need Dispatcher here?

Comment: Mmh... I'm not familiar with "Events model". Can you point me to the documentation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At a certain point I wanna stop parallelism and I want to make the calls sequential (following their order). I'd like to create a sort of channel. To do so I need a thread called, maybe, ChannelThread. If I had the dispatcher of that thread I can just call the functions on that dispatcher. So, I'll be sure the calls happen sequentially.

First, stop thinking in terms of threads. At this point in software development, threads are an implementation detail. I recommend adopting the highest-level solution available.

Two that come immediately to mind are Reactive Extensions (Rx) and TPL Dataflow. Since there isn't much context in your question, it's difficult to say how easily Rx would integrate with your solution. TPL Dataflow provides a simple FIFO buffer that you can use like this:

```
var fifo = new ActionBlock<Action>(action => action());
```

By default, dataflow blocks execute on the thread pool and limit their concurrency to one-at-a-time, so that's all you need.

To queue work to the block:

```
fifo.Post(() => { /* work */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not get the work thread dispatcher in Windows Runtime App. In .NET for Desktop, there is a Dispatcher class which is used to manage the queue of work items for a thread. But in Windows Runtime, only the UI thread has the dispatcher named CoreDispatcher.

To submit a work item to background thread pool. You can use method Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync.

[Using the thread pool in Windows Runtime apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465290.aspx)

To run the work item sequentially, you can use the await key-word.

For example:

```
await RunTask1Async();
await RunTask1Async();
```

Or use the Task class

```
    var task = new Task(()=> {
        // work1
    }).ContinueWith((t)=> {
        // work2
    });
```